# Questions about contract calling another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Need help with two related Solidity questions.

1. Question 1. Say, I have a contract calling another one:

   ```
   contract B {
     function f1() {
        ...
     }
   }

   contract A {
     B b;

     function f() {
       b.f1();
     }
   }
   ```

Will `msg.sender` for `f1` be same as for `f()`? Of will it be an address of a contract `A`?

2. Question 2.
   Say, I have contracts A and B.
   I want to have

   ```
   contract A {
     B b;

     A(address addr) { 
       b = B(addr); 
     }
   }
   ```

In other language, I would use `B b = null;` in declaration, to avoid double initialization, but it does not work in Solidity. So how do I declare a member variable and then initialize it by address?

Comment: Thanks, Adam. But to the second question: when I declare B b;, a default constructor should be called, right? And so I pay for it...

Comment: No, constructors are only called once and there is only one constructor per contract (From https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/control-structures.rst#scoping-and-declarations: "When a contract is created, its constructor (a function with the same name as the contract) is executed once. A constructor is optional. Only one constructor is allowed, and this means overloading is not supported."). Contract variables will be initialized to internal byte representation for 0. See https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/docs/control-structures.rst#scoping-and-declarations.

Answer (score 3):

> Will msg.sender for f1 be same as for f()? Of will it be an address of
>   a contract A?

`msg.sender` will be the address of contract A. If you want to reference the original caller, use `tx.origin`.

> So how do I declare a member variable and then initialize it by
>   address?

You don't need to worry about initialization when you declare the member variable. All variables in Solidity have default values. You can follow something like this:

```
contract B {
    address sender;

    function B(address addr) {
        sender = addr;
    }
}

contract A {
    B b;

    function A(){
        b = B(msg.sender);
    }
}
```