# msg.sender is different in internal call

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm new to `solidity` & `ethereum` development.

Let's say I have the following structure ( mine is a more complicated, but I think this will work for now ) :

```
contract A {
  address public owner;
  function A() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
  }

  isOwner(address _addr) {
      return _addr == owner;
  }
}

contract Base is A { 
     ....
     someMethod(address _addr) {
        require(isOwner(msg.sender))

        // do something with _addr
     }
}

contract SomeContract{
     Base public baseContract;
     function SomeContract(Base _base) { 
        baseContract = _base
     }
     callingMethod() {
        ....
        require(baseContract.someMethod(msg.sender))
        ....
     }
}
```

By calling `callingMethod` from `truffle`, it fails because of `require(isOwner(msg.sender))`. I was able to see that `msg.sender` is different from owner using an `Event` and printing its result to console, but I don't understand why.

Anyone knows why is this happening? Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions about contract calling another contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47858489/questions-about-contract-calling-another-contract)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that msg.sender changes to address of the calling contract, i.e. SomeContract in your case. Consider using Base contract as a [library](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#libraries), for example. msg.sender would not be changed in that case as far [DELEGATECALL](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html?highlight=DELEGATECALL#delegatecall-callcode-and-libraries) but not regular Message Call will be used under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

`msg.sender` might represent either user address or another contract address.

Usually it is an user address, however when inside your contract this contract calls another contract `msg.sender` would be an address of the contract caller – not an address which was defined during the initial call, e.g. `contract.connect(<signer>)`.

It might be important during `ERC721` token approve call: we could approve one address, but eventually authorized `ERC721` token function would be called by deployed contract which would end up with revered tx as this address has not been approved.